# Git (windows 7) won't add directories, but adds files files typed explicitly

Tags: windows, git

trying to find an answer to this, have seen it hinted at, but no solution.

Not entirely new to git, but haven't used it in a few months... this is my first time using it on windows. using git bash.

I have a cake PHP site that I want to add exluding any cache files **my .gitignore file contains only:**

app/tmp/*

Here is the most basic thing I have tried:

```
git init
git add .
git commit
```

I get a message on commit saying there are untracked files - all files and dirs at the root directory.

```
git status
```

gives me the same message.

However, if I type

```
git add .htaccess
```

it stages the .htaccess file.

Also, if I do:

```
git add app/.htaccess
```

It will add that file too.

I have also tried

```
git add app/*
```

no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After running `git add .`, run `git status`. What does it say? Do you have cake's git directory still in there?

Comment: status says same as git commit - unstaged files message. will add that to question. Also, no I do not have cake's git repo in there. assuming it would be at the root.

Comment: Also post `git config --list` (hide sensitive data). What you have in your question should work on a fresh git repo.

Comment: Have accidentally ignored all files? Either in .gitignore or .git/info/exclude?

Answer (score 0):

The files aren't ignored, because otherwise you would be forced to do a `git add --force afile`.

However, you might want to check `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable, and see if they reference another repository, which could explain the discrepancy between the index and what you think is your working tree.